# How to make a vue property conditional with another property in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Probably this is TOO basic - but nowadays I'm all kinda noob.
I'm studying VueJS and I'm stuck in one problem.

I have this `<h3>` and its style is binded to a Vue Object.

```
<h3 :style="headerStyleP2" class="p2 font-ranchers col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
   P2
</h3>
```

And here's the Vue object....

```
var notas = new Vue({
  el: '#notas',
  data: {
    obs1: "Digite a nota da P1",
    obs2: "",
    obs3: "",
    input1: "",
    input2: "",
    input3: "",
    inputStyle: {
      color: "white"
    },
    headerStyleP2: {
      color: this.input1 ? "blue" : "grey"
    },
    headerStyleP3: {
      color: "aqua"
    }
  }
})
```

So there you guys can see that I'm using a ternary. It's kinda working - but it's not being dynamic. When I refresh the page it's grey - but it never turns blue when I change the input1 value. (it's binded to another input - this one is working great.)

I'm felling I'm doing this the wrong way. How can I make it work?

Comment: Do a computed property for it please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `headerStyleP2` to be a computed property instead so it will always recompute with the latest value of `this.input1`. More info about [computed properties here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties).

```html
<h3 :style="headerStyleP2" class="p2 font-ranchers col-xs-6 col-sm-12">...</h3>
```

```js
computed: {
  headerStyleP2() {
    return { color: this.input1 ? "blue" : "grey" };
  }
}
```

[image]

Here's a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-poincare-m2bkg?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue).

Comment: I'd like to say one thing, mister - please keep being this extremely helpful guy. It's wonderful that you even made a gif. Thank you so much. Worked beautifully.

Comment: You're welcome. Just doing what I can to help out a fellow coder. Goodluck!